# Variadic template for concisely defining a tuple whose components are all the same type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++14, variadic

C++11 provides a `std::tuple` template, but it requires the types of all the fields to be listed individually, which is inconvenient if there are many fields and they're all the same type.  If I want a tuple of, say, 10 integers, instead of writing `std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int>`, I'd like to be able to just write something like `tuple_of<10, int>`.

To that end, I've written a template that expands a number into that many copies of a type:

```
template <unsigned int n, typename T>
struct tuple_of {
private:

  // Adds another copy of T to the list
  template <unsigned int m, typename... Ts>
  struct tuple_builder {
    using type = typename tuple_builder<m-1, T, Ts...>::type;
  };

  // Makes a tuple out of all the copies of T that have been listed
  template <typename... Ts>
  struct tuple_builder<0, Ts...> {
    using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
  };

public:

  tuple_of() = delete;  // Prevent accidental instantiation

  using type = typename tuple_builder<n, T>::type;
};

// Convenience alias
template <unsigned int n, typename T>
using tuple_of_t = typename tuple_of<n, T>::type;
```

Now you can write either `tuple_of<10, int>::type` or `tuple_of_t<10, int>`.

This works, but it seems a little awkward.  A few things in particular bother me:

- I don't really like having to write either `::type` or the `_t` suffix of the convenience alias; I'd rather just write `tuple_of<10, int>`.  I've followed the pattern established by the templates in the standard `<type_traits>` header — e.g. `std::result_of_t<T>` is an alias for `std::result_of<T>::type` — but `tuple_of` isn't a type trait so I don't know if I *should* be following that convention.
- I've made the template a `struct` because that seems to be the norm for templates used in metaprogramming, but it contains a private helper template that I don't really want to expose, and it's a little weird to have private stuff in a `struct`.
- This is the first variadic template I've written, so I'm not sure that my `tuple_builder` is the most elegant way to build a list of *n* copies of a type.
- While testing, I accidentally created an instance of the template type itself, rather than the tuple type it produces, by writing `tuple_of<10, int>` instead of `tuple_of<10, int>::type`.  To avoid that mistake in the future, I deleted the constructor.  I don't know whether that's something templates like this "should" do; the templates in `<type_traits>` don't have deleted constructors.

Can this template be improved?

Comment: What is wrong with `std::array<int, 10>`?

Comment: That could probably work, but I'd like to have compile-time checking that I'm only accessing valid elements.  With `std::array`, it looks like `operator[]` doesn't prevent out-of-bounds access, and `at()` checks at runtime.  Using `std::get<n>` on a tuple will fail to compile if `n` is past the end of the tuple.

Comment: Ahh, nevermind, I see that `std::get` works with `std::array` too.  And [the page on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) even mentions that "an array can also be used as a tuple of N elements of the same type."

Comment: If the types are all the same. Then we are talking about an array.

Answer (score 1):

As [nwp](/users/47624/nwp) pointed out in a comment, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a better choice for this.  I didn't need to write this template at all.